# Emgu CV Ram issue

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have about 100 images, So I started sending them one by one to the `ProcessImage` function. and it keeps using so much Ram until it reaches around 5-GB and then my program crashes
As mentioned: `.SmoothGaussian` performs Gaussian Smoothing in the current image and returns the result.

Please Note:I started removing some parts of my code, until I reached a point where I was 100% that, my Ram issue is caused by the highlighted line of code in specific! Also I am using Emgu CV version 3.4.3

I tried typing both: `temp.Dispose();` and `temp=null();` after declaring it but didn't work!

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;

private void OpenFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Multiselect = true;
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < open.FileNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            using (Image<Bgr, byte> ToProcess = new Image<Bgr,byte> (open.FileNames[i]))
            {
                ProcessImage(ToProcess, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProcessImage function:

```
private void ProcessImage (Image<Bgr, byte> imgInput, int counter)
{
    //This line of code causes the problem!
    var temp = imgInput.SmoothGaussian(5);
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I haven't used `emgucv` but you are chaining few functions in that call. If you can separate those, maybe you get the exact call which blows the RAM.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Thanks I followed your advice.

Comment: So, it is still the `SmoothGaussian` that is causing the problem. If you are debugging in VS, can you see that memory goes down after `ProcessImage` returns? It should go down after processing an image. Otherwise, it means that this function is leaking memory.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot So I followed that and I can see that 99% of the time, it just rises. and if it goes down, it won't be more than 10MB (which happens only after the GB works).

Comment: Well, I tried it on a set of 120 JPEG images and `WorkingSet64` is consistently 55MB but `prefcounter` report working set between 36180K to 189896K. I'm using Windows 10 x64 build 1803 with 32G RAM and Xenon processor.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I created a new fresh program with those two functions only. so the problem seems to stay!

Comment: Try putting `GC.Collect()` after all.

Comment: @HaBom didn't help

Comment: I had the same issus as you when I open a video. Did you try to put `GC.Collect()`at the end in every for loop? Like this:                                       
     
    ```for (int i = 0; i < open.FileNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                using (Image<Bgr, byte> ToProcess = new Image<Bgr,byte> (open.FileNames[i]))
                {
                    ProcessImage(ToProcess, i);
                }
                GC.Collect();
            }
    ```